# What is the difference between Debug Mode and Release Mode in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Debug/Release difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367884/debug-release-difference)
>   [Performance differences between debug and release builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043821/performance-differences-between-debug-and-release-builds)

What exactly is the different in compiling and running an asp.net/c# project in Debug mode VS Release Mode?

Comment: Exact dupe : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933739/what-is-difference-between-release-and-debug-modes-in-visual-studio

Comment: Dupe 2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367884/debug-release-difference

Comment: Dupe 3 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143244/visual-studio-debug-vs-release

Comment: And Dupe 4 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043821/performance-differences-between-debug-and-release-builds

Comment: Use the SO/google search http://www.google.com/search?q=difference+between+debug+and+release+visual+studio&sitesearch=stackoverflow.com/questions&qscrl=1

Comment: @Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen and that would be 4! lol

Comment: For the record, no difference in Visual Studio 2010 and in `ASP.NET` environment it means the debug information is inserted to the `DLL` file of the web application.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In **Debug Mode** your `.exe` has **debug information** inside of it (source code, variable names and other similar stuff like that).

In **Release Mode** your `.exe` lack of **debug information** makes it smaller and probably performs better due to its smaller footprint.

Comment: Biggest diff is probably that in Release, many optimizations are turned on to make the program perform better, that would normally hamper the ability to debug the program. So it's not just the lack of debug info that is the difference.

Answer (score 4):

The biggest difference between these is that:
In a debug build the complete symbolic debug information is emitted to help while debugging applications and also the code optimization is not taken into account.
While in release build the symbolic debug info is not emitted and the code execution is optimized.
Also, because the symbolic info is not emitted in a release build, the size of the final executable is lesser than a debug executable.

One can expect to see funny errors in release builds due to compiler optimizations or differences in memory layout or initialization. These are ususally referred to as Release - Only bugs :)

In terms of execution speed, a release executable will execute faster for sure, but not always will this different be significant.

Answer (score 1):

Other compile arguments who giving you more debug info in producted executable and many more options who you wan read at msdn.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/74db169a-e244-496e-ae97-8dfec18ff2e5