# What is the difference between Release configuration and compilation debug=false?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio, we can choose between Release and Debug from a quick menu at the top of the IDE window.  Easy.  However, selecting Release from this menu does not remove `debug="true"` from the `Web.config` file.  Check out the image.  I can select Release, but the config file doesn't change.  If `debug="true"` remains in the config file, is there any real difference in choosing one configuration over another from the menu?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option compilation debug=true from web.config is linked to ASP.NET only. You will have more temporary ASP.NET files, no page timeout, it determines if aspx pages are compiled in debug mode. See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/prashant_upadhyay/archive/2011/07/15/pros-and-cons-of-using-debug-true-in-asp-net-applications-in-production-environment.aspx) what it activates.

Debug/Release is linked to how you compile your c# code into Dlls. When Release is activated you don't have the debug information and several optimizations are not done. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338733/what-is-the-difference-between-debug-mode-and-release-mode-in-visual-studio-2010) for more information.

Comment: Excellent answer with very relevant links.

Comment: Thank you!  Actually, I had no idea about the page timeout aspect.  That shines light on a problem a coworker is having.