# Visual Studio publish in debug Vs Release mode

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, deployment

I know the difference between debug and release mode BUILD. But I have a small doubt, does it make any difference on what mode I select while publishing the application thru Visual studio?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you publish using `Debug mode`, your generated files have debugging enabled and that will impact the performance.

It is always recommended that you publish website in `Release Mode`

Please read this
[Don’t run production ASP.NET Applications with debug=”true” enabled](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/442448)

Comment: by default VS should publish in release mode, isn't it? what is the purpose of publishing in debug mode.

Comment: by default it publish in debug mode, you have to set release mode explicitly in project properties. Please read the article in the answer.

Comment: please can i ask:
1- should i publish always in release mode in production environment.
2- is this true in web applications and web sites?

Comment: 3- is there any changes in framework 3.5 ??because the article a bout framework 1.1

Comment: yes, you have to publish your website in release mode for both website and web application. Regarding Framework, we are publish website 3.5 and even 4.0, I don't see any difference.

Comment: Pang , Just to make sure i understand. Can i publish in DEBUG MODE with the PDB and then change the attribute Applications with debug=”false” and it will be fast as it would be if i publish in Release Mode?

Answer (score 4):

Refered to [How to: Set Debug and Release Configurations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx0123s5.aspx)

> The Debug configuration of your
>   program is compiled with full symbolic
>   debug information and no optimization.
>   Optimization complicates debugging,
>   because the relationship between
>   source code and generated instructions
>   is more complex.
>
> The Release configuration of your
>   program contains no symbolic debug
>   information and is fully optimized.
>   Debug information can be generated in
>   Program Database Files (C++),
>   depending on the compiler options that
>   are used. Creating PDB files can be
>   very useful if you later have to debug
>   your release version.

Take a look at [Visual Studio - Debug vs Release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143244/visual-studio-debug-vs-release)